# How many states would a Turing Machine need to decide this language?

Tags: turing-machines, states

The language L = {1^200}, or rather, the language such that there are 200 1's in a row?  Aka, this TM only accepts once it receives 200 '1's in a row.  Would it therefore need 200 states to solve this, or could this be simplified with less states?

I'm asking this to help understand how TM's work.

note: The alphabet would be just {1}.  The TM can use as many tapes as you'd like.

Comment: Does L consist of only the single sentence 1^200, or any string that starts with 1^200?

Answer (score 0):

I assume L only contains the single sentence 1^200. Then, it all depends on what you define as the alphabet. If you define '1' as an alphabet, you need 201 states including the initial state. If you defined the string 1^200 as an 'alphabet', then you only need two states: the initial state and the end state, connected with an arrow labeled 1^200.

Comment: Assume the alphabet is just {1}.  So would it be possible to simplify this?  For example, maybe pushing two 1's on per state and stopping when it gets to the 100th state?

Comment: Pushing two 1's at a time means you are handeling '11' as a single alphabet.

Comment: well by at a time, I meant during one state.  Like, could I push two 1's on during one state, then move to the next state?  Not at the "same time" necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

For a deterministic finite automaton, you would need 201 states like @sawa said.  However, a Turing machine might be able to keep a counter and then compare it against 200, which could be done with fewer states.  The number of states required depends on your Turing machine model; a multi-tape machine could probably use fewer states, but a one-tape machine will probably require 201.

Answer (score 0):

With two tapes, or a tape alphabet (different from the input alphabet) larger than simply {1,blank}, one can do much better.  In fact, the only thing that you need the second tape or extended alphabet for is marking where the beginning and end of the input are.

So we can begin as follows: run over the input erasing every other 1.  Simultaneously, we can count the parity of the length of the input.  This can be done with only two states, call them EVEN and ODD.  Start in the EVEN state.  When you read a 1, switch to the ODD state.  In the ODD state, when you read a 1, erase it and switch to the EVEN state.

Then go back doing the same thing using two more states.  Then go over the input a third time with two more states.  At this point, either your machine has rejected when one of the sweeps read an odd number of 1's, or else you now have 1/8th as many 1's.

Using a similar construction, you can run over the input erasing 4 out of every 5 1's and making sure the length of the input is a multiple of 5.  It can be done with 5 states.  Do that twice.

Now, if all the parity and (5-arity) checks pass and you are left with a single 1, then your original input had 1*5*5*2*2*2=200 1's in it.  Otherwise not.  Total states used: 2+2+2+5+5=16 (or 18 if you count your accept and reject states).

Fancier constructions can do the same task in fewer states, but you are pretty much guaranteed that the runtimes will be ridiculous and you will need a tape alphabet of at least {0,1,blank}.  If you really want to get a good handle on how Turing Machines work, think about how the algorithm makes up for the Turing Machine's lack of random access memory (in the form of states).  Could you make a similar algorithm for the language {1^99}?  What about {1^97} (hint: it can be done with fewer than 97 states, but you'll need some new cleverness)?